# Overclocking RAM fails

Tags: memory, overclocking, amd-ryzen

I recently have gotten a motherboard ([Prime B350-PLUS](https://www.asus.com/us/Motherboards/PRIME-B350-PLUS/)) with a CPU ([AMD Ryzen 5 1600](https://www.amd.com/en/products/cpu/amd-ryzen-5-1600)) and some RAM ([2x4GB 3000MHz, Corsair Vengeance](http://www.corsair.com/en-us/vengeance-lpx-8gb-2x4gb-ddr4-dram-3000mhz-c15-memory-kit-red-cmk8gx4m2b3000c15r)).

On default my motherboard sets the RAM frequency to 2133MHz and the voltage to 1.2V. If I try to change the frequency to 2933MHz and the voltage to 1.35V, it boots a few times with 3 short beeps, then once with 1 short beep, then again once with 1 short beep to say "Overclocking has failed.".

What am I doing wrong? Is the voltage too low?

BTW: When I try to use the preset RAM overclocking profile, it just boots once, without any beeps. The fans turn on but everything else remains unpowered and dark. On a restart the same thing happens. I waited for 2 minutes but nothing happened. I had to remove the CMOS and put it in again to fix it. Then everything again runs fine, but only on the default 2133MHz - 1.2V. I've got the latest BIOS update and my RAM sticks are in the recommended slots.

How could I achieve my desired speed? What could be wrong?

Comment: Try with a reduced overclock first, and see if you can get that to work. Also, contact other users with that motherboard, and see what they've been able to achieve.

Comment: The RAM modules are just a guess. What is the actual configuration you got the modules in, in regards to the used slots? As per the information page for the motherboard: `1*Due to the limitation of AMD Ryzen™ processors, memory frequencies higher than DDR4 2666 MHz are supported only when using one DIMM per channel.`.

Comment: @Seth I've got my RAM in position A2 and B2 (2 and 4) - like shown [here](https://dlsvr04.asus.com/pub/ASUS/mb/SocketAM4/PRIME_B350-PLUS/E12581_PRIME_B350-PLUS_UM_V2_WEB_20170329.pdf) (Page 1-12)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION:**

I had the BIOS version 0609 and it didn't work.
A few days ago a new BIOS version was released (0803 BETA) for my motherboard.
I updated, put my RAM to 2933MHz, 1.3 volts and 15-17-17(-17)-35 timings and it worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

The base clock of the system is 533. You therefore should use multipliers of that.

Set the RAM to 2666 and the voltage to 1.35V. There is no reason for it not to work on this configuration. For higher than this, you need higher clocked RAM. A 3200MHz module would of been ideal for your system if you want the RAM at higher clocks.

For intermediary experimenting, post some screen shots with your OC settings options. There may be other valid variants.

Comment: Sorry, but why would I need 3200MHz RAM instead of 3000MHz RAM to reach just 2933MHz?

Comment: Because 2933MHz is not a multiplier of the base frequency, therefore you cannot set it without very deep modifications. Details about what settings you can actually do can help a lot further determinations.

Comment: Well but I can set my RAM frequency to 2400MHz, which also isn't a multiplier of 533. Why does that work then? 2666MHz also works..

Comment: 2666 is normal to work. 2400 is a half-multiplier one, and can work well in certain conditions (with a 4.5 multi), that's why I asked about settings capability details. Logically, if a 4.5 multi would work, so should a 5.5 one (for 2933). Since it does not, either the modules can't handle the settings or the settings must be tweaked way more.